# Is this a termite wing or flying ant wing

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I saw this on the bottom corner of my pantry in the Washington DC area. I can't tell whether is termite wing or something else. The wing is 3/4" long.
[image: insect wing on off-white background]

Comment: I agree it is a great photo but as a person who has had both problems, can you give more details, inside outside any debris ? And where in the world are you! In the Pacific Northwest I can say yes it is!!! Oops not much info so my answer oops comment could be?

Comment: If you don't find an answere here find an entomology forum or "what's this bug" because the ID is very specialized entomology.

Comment: FYI the [Comstock-Needham system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comstock%E2%80%93Needham_system) might be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the wing of a crane fly (Tipulidae).  Using [this figure](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336657048/figure/fig1/AS:815518441299968@1571446156600/Insect-wing-venation-patterns-wing-contour-and-shapes-of-vein-bounded-domains-Adapted.png) you can begin narrowing down the possibilities for wing venation. Searching *diptera wing venation*, I think, brings up [this excellent diagram](https://www.batsdiet.com/arthropod-morphology/diptera#wing) (see bottom left for Tipulidae) which quite closely matches your photo if rotated in a graphics program (GIMP):

[image: Click to zoom]

<sup>Wing photo from OP paired with wing outline image copied and rotated from [Batsdiet.com](https://www.batsdiet.com/arthropod-morphology/diptera#wing)</sup>

You could likely drill this down further by searching *Tipulidae venation* or the like on Google Scholar, which pulls up many papers with detailed information on various regions and taxa of crane flies.

Comment: You might further cite evidence that crane flies have wings this size. For example, quickly [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_fly) suggests they can range from 1-6.5(11) cm, which safely includes the size of the OP's specimen. You might also note that crane flies *are* present in DC.